# How can I call an object's method from within a format string? (Python)

Tags: python, string

I want to call a string's lower method from within the template string. This would ideally look something like

```py
string = "Lowercase: {value.lower()}"

string.format(value=...)
```

However, this gives me an error saying `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'lower()'` (I understand why I'm getting this error).

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this. I've looked at using conversion (like `'{value!r}` for calling `repr`) but that didn't fix my problem. Could I create a custom conversion specifier?

(For the record, `string.format(value=value.lower())` will not necessarily work in my case.)

Comment: Did you mean to use an f-string? Note the "f" prefix: `f"Lowercase: {value.lower()}"`

Comment: No, value is going to be a keyword passed into `string.format(...)`, not necessarily a variable on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC, the format specification mini-language can access attributes of objects, but it can't call methods. It assumes you're looking for an attribute with the name "lower()", parentheses included.

Does `value` have to be a string? Perhaps you could create a string subclass with a `@property` that returns a lowercased version of itself. For example:

```
class StringEx(str):
    @property
    def lowercase(self):
        return self.lower()

x = StringEx("Hello, World!")
s = "Lowercase: {value.lowercase}"
print(s.format(value=x))
```

Result:

```
Lowercase: hello, world!
```

---

If you expect to have a lot of different format strings and don't want to implement a property for each string method, you can cover all the zero-argument methods in one go by overriding `__getattr__`:

```
class StringEx(str):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name.endswith("()"):
            return getattr(self, name[:-2])()
        else:
            raise AttributeError

x = StringEx("HeLlO, WoRlD!")
format_strings = [
    "Regular: {value}",
    "Lowercase: {value.lower()}",
    "Uppercase: {value.upper()}",
    "Title: {value.title()}"
]

for s in format_strings:
    print(s.format(value=x))
```

Result:

```
Regular: HeLlO, WoRlD!
Lowercase: hello, world!
Uppercase: HELLO, WORLD!
Title: Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use f-str, this will help.

```
value = "HELLO world"
f"Lowercase: {value.lower()}"
```